# Cannot find the file URL using xhr.open('post',url,true) - Status: 404 node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, path, xmlhttprequest

Trying to Upload an image by `XMLHttpRequest()`, have issue understanding what is the correct URL to access file via `xhr.open(...)`.

Following [this](http://www.hartzis.me/react-image-upload/#xhrajax-image-upload) example for server side code and everything..

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('post','../../../../server/routes/saveImage.js',true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status ==200) {
      resolve(this.response);
    } else {
      reject (this.statusText);
    }
  };
```

The Project directory is something like this

- Project

  - client

    - app

      - component

        - product

          - addproduct.js **<-- xhr.open is called from here**
  - server

    - routes

      - saveImage.js **<-- File being called**

Also regarding paths let me know if there is a more convenient way to check the access path or absolute path to use in url.

Comment: Is the saveImage.js exposed for the client to see?

Comment: how do i make sure it is exposed?

Comment: What does your node.js app look like/where you set up your routes?

Comment: based on the answer below I think i require more understanding on server side. Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed was with setting up a server side route, this was mostly clarified, thanks to the answer from @Arkita and comment from @Kasper. But I went ahead to dig for a solution, which may not be very useful to others as this was a dumb question in the first place, but here it goes..

On client side

```
xhr.open('post','/saveImage/save',true);
```

on server side if you are using Express.js or other connect based frameworks

```
app.post('/saveImage/save',(req,res,next)=> {....})
```

Also the example I linked above may be outdated, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qzmri1WaaE) seems more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a conceptual problem in many levels.

First, When you are XHRing(ajax) an url that means you are accessing the url from CLIENT SIDE. So, Let's say you have an app and HTTP posting or getting an url. Do you have that file from client side? The answer is obviously NO.
let's say you are hosting the app in:

```
http://localhost/myapps/app
```

So, When you access `./someFile.txt`, `../someFile.txt` and `../../someFile.txt` you are actually requesting

```
./someFile.txt-> http://localhost/myapps/app/someFile.txt
../someFile.txt-> http://localhost/myapps/someFile.txt
../../someFile.txt-> http://localhost/someFile.txt
```

Now, For your problem. You need to **host** the `Server Side` upload code somewhere. The example assumes the Server Side code is hosted in, for example, `http://localhost/upload` and use `xhr.open('post','/upload',true);`

You need to understand `require`ing or `import`ing or `fs.readFile` a file is accessing the path internally. But when you host the app, any client side code like Ajax(XHR) is accessing the url from outside.

Comment: I agree with the conceptual issue, i assumed this would work just the way require or fetch etc. works. I'm new to Node Js.. Can you point me in the right direction with an article? so I can look more in depth. Because "Host the server side upload somewhere" is still beyond me. Thanks for your time!